# Not receiving emails [phpmailer]

Tags: php, wordpress

Using **phpmailer** to send email when someone will fill form and click on submit. But, don't know why its not sending email at set address (n*****b@gmail.com)

**Code is as below:**

```
<?php 
function notifiyCustomerOnNewOrderCreation($orderDetails, $order_id = '', $update = false)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $orderHTML = makeHTMLfromOrderDetails($orderDetails);
    $order_link = admin_url('admin.php?page=cust_edit_order&id=' . str_replace("#", "*", $order_id));
    $userId = $orderDetails->OD("user_id");
    $userDetails = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT display_name,user_email FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE ID ='{$userId}' LIMIT 1");
    global $phpmailer;
    // (Re)create it, if it's gone missing
    if ( !is_object( $phpmailer ) || !is_a( $phpmailer, 'PHPMailer' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpmailer.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-smtp.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer( true );
    } else { $mail = clone $phpmailer; }
    $mail->IsSendmail();
    if($userDetails){
    foreach($userDetails as $ca){
    try {
    $mail->AddAddress($ca->user_email, $ca->display_name);
    $mail->AddAddress('n*****b@gmail.com', 'Navnish Bhardwaj');
    if($update){
    $mail->Subject = 'Your order has been updated. ' . "[{$order_id}]";
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
    $mail->MsgHTML("Your order has been updated.<br/><a href='{$order_link}'>View Order</a><br/>" . $orderHTML);
    } else {
    $mail->Subject = 'Your order has been created. ' . "[{$order_id}]";
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
    $mail->MsgHTML("Your order has been created.<br/><a href='{$order_link}'>View Order</a><br/>" . $orderHTML);
    }
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    } catch(phpmailerException $e){ return false; } 
    catch(Exception $e){ return false; }
    } } return true;
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Need more info. Need live example. Need expected output (picture)

Comment: Where's the fiddle???

Comment: @J148 A JSFiddle link is not required to ask a question on StackOverflow. You're free to make one yourself, however.

Comment: Based on what you have provided the contents are centred [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kus3mq27/)

Comment: It was a joke (where's the beef), but point taken. Also that little bit of code doesn't show much. Everything already looks centered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're asking for, but I assume you want to center a div inside of its parent container. To do that, the `div` must have a `width` smaller than the width of the parent container (of course), it must be `display: block`, and have `margin: 0 auto`.

You can also center an element with `display: inline-block` or `display: inline` by using `text-align: center` on the parent element. This will center the text inside as well. I think this may be what you want, since you said you wanted to align everything to the center. Just put it all into the `div`.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="centerthis">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
}

.centerthis {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

OR:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.centerthis {
    display: inline-block; /*or inline*/
    width: 50%;
}
```

[Check out this demo to see it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/e8zrz58n/)

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this to solve your problem

Try the css within your page head section

```
`   <style type="text/css">
       .cxxc {
          margin: 0 auto 0 0;
          border:1px solid;
        }
       .cxxc .alignCenter{
          width:100%;
          margin:0 auto 0 auto;
          border:1px solid;
          text-align:center;
       }
       #a{
          text-align:center;
          color: #80080;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 24px;
          margin: 30px 0 0 0px;
       } 
    </style>    `
```

Try the html within your page body section

```
<div id="a"></div>
   <br/><br/>
   <div class="cxxc">
   <div class='alignCenter'></div>
</div>
```

#### Enter your all contents within 'alignCenter' div to align all data to the center